# How can i improve GROUP BY statement performance?

Tags: mysql

I have a big query that i need to optimize.

```
select game_id,
       count(user_id),
       count(distinct user_id),
       provider_id,
       aggregator,
       country,
       sum(sum_bets),
       sum(sum_wins),
       currency,
       any_value(date)
from (select transactions.game_id                                            as game_id,
             transactions.user_id                                            as user_id,
             games.provider_id                                               as provider_id,
             games.aggregator                                                as aggregator,
             users.country                                                   as country,
             transactions.currency                                           as currency,
             IF(transactions.type_id IN (2, 16), transactions.amount, 0)     as sum_bets,
             IF(transactions.type_id IN (3, 18, 20), transactions.amount, 0) as sum_wins,
             transactions.date_create                                        as date
      from `transactions`
               inner join `games` on transactions.game_id = games.id
               inner join `users` on transactions.user_id = users.id
      where transactions.status_id = 1
        and transactions.type_id in (2, 3, 16, 18, 20)
        and transactions.game_id is not null
        and users.country is not null
      union all
      select transactions_bonus.game_id                                                    as game_id,
             transactions_bonus.user_id                                                    as user_id,
             games.provider_id                                                             as provider_id,
             games.aggregator                                                              as aggregator,
             users.country                                                                 as country,
             transactions_bonus.currency                                                   as currency,
             IF(transactions_bonus.type IN (5, 6), transactions_bonus.amount_bonus, 0)     as sum_bets,
             IF(transactions_bonus.type IN (4, 7, 10), transactions_bonus.amount_bonus, 0) as sum_wins,
             transactions_bonus.date                                                       as date
      from `transactions_bonus`
               inner join `games` on transactions_bonus.game_id = games.id
               inner join `users` on transactions_bonus.user_id = users.id
      where transactions_bonus.status in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        and transactions_bonus.type in (4, 5, 6, 7, 10)
        and transactions_bonus.game_id is not null
        and users.country is not null) as popular_games
group by game_id, provider_id, aggregator, country, currency
```

Table transactions

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table transactions
(
    id                  bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    string_id           varchar(36)                            null,
    user_id             bigint unsigned                        not null,
    game_id             smallint unsigned                      null,
    bonus_id            smallint unsigned                      null,
    jackpot_id          bigint unsigned                        null,
    prize_id            bigint unsigned                        null,
    tournament_id       bigint unsigned                        null,
    amount              int                                    not null,
    commission          int                                    null,
    aggregator_amount   int unsigned default '0'               not null,
    aggregator_currency varchar(16) collate utf8_bin           null,
    aggregator_fee      int unsigned default '0'               not null,
    currency            varchar(3)                             not null,
    status_id           tinyint unsigned                       not null,
    balance             int                                    null,
    gateway_method      varchar(64)                            null,
    account             varchar(128) collate utf8_bin          null comment 'Аккаунт в платежной системе (номер карты, телефон, кошелек)',
    ip                  varchar(39)                            null,
    comment             varchar(128)                           null,
    date_create         datetime     default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    date_complete       datetime                               null,
    date_cancel         datetime                               null,
    type_id             tinyint unsigned                       not null,
    manager_id          int                                    null,
    event_id            int                                    null,
    constraint transactions_ibfk_1
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_ibfk_2
        foreign key (game_id) references games (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_ibfk_3
        foreign key (jackpot_id) references jackpots (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_ibfk_4
        foreign key (tournament_id) references tournaments (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_prize_id_foreign
        foreign key (prize_id) references prizes (id)
            on update cascade
)
    engine = InnoDB;

create index date_create
    on transactions (date_create);

create index game_id
    on transactions (game_id);

create index jackpot_id
    on transactions (jackpot_id);

create index string_id
    on transactions (string_id);

create index tournament_id
    on transactions (tournament_id);

create index type_id
    on transactions (type_id);

create index user_id
    on transactions (user_id);
```

Table transactions_bonus

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table transactions_bonus
(
    id                     bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    account                tinyint unsigned default '1'               not null comment 'Номер счета. 1 - бонусный счет казино, 2 - бонусный счет спорта',
    type                   tinyint unsigned                           not null,
    user_id                bigint unsigned                            not null,
    admin_id               bigint unsigned                            null,
    transaction_id         bigint unsigned                            null,
    bonus_id               bigint unsigned                            null,
    tournament_id          bigint unsigned                            null,
    prize_id               bigint unsigned                            null,
    game_id                smallint unsigned                          null,
    amount_bonus           int                                        not null,
    amount_deposit         int                                        null,
    currency               varchar(3)                                 not null,
    wager                  float                                      not null,
    max_bet                int unsigned                               null,
    max_transfer           int unsigned     default '0'               not null comment 'Максимальная сумма перевода с бонусного счета на основной',
    balance                int                                        not null,
    status                 tinyint unsigned                           not null,
    comment                text                                       null,
    date                   timestamp        default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    date_cancel            timestamp                                  null,
    date_wagering_complete timestamp                                  null,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_1
        foreign key (admin_id) references users (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_3
        foreign key (tournament_id) references tournaments (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_4
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_5
        foreign key (game_id) references games (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_6
        foreign key (prize_id) references prizes (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_7
        foreign key (bonus_id) references bonuses (id)
            on update cascade,
    constraint transactions_bonus_ibfk_8
        foreign key (transaction_id) references transactions (id)
            on update cascade
)
    engine = InnoDB;

create index account
    on transactions_bonus (account);

create index admin_id
    on transactions_bonus (admin_id);

create index bonus_id
    on transactions_bonus (bonus_id);

create index game_id
    on transactions_bonus (game_id);

create index status
    on transactions_bonus (status);

create index tournament_id
    on transactions_bonus (tournament_id);

create index transaction_id_2
    on transactions_bonus (transaction_id);

create index type
    on transactions_bonus (type);

create index user_id
    on transactions_bonus (user_id);
```

Table games

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table games
(
    id                     smallint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    string_id              varchar(96) collate utf8_bin                     not null,
    provider_id            tinyint unsigned                                 not null,
    aggregator             tinyint unsigned                                 not null,
    name                   varchar(255)                                     not null,
    game_type              tinyint unsigned                                 not null,
    source                 tinyint unsigned                                 not null,
    technology             tinyint unsigned                                 not null,
    device_type            tinyint unsigned                                 not null,
    status                 tinyint unsigned       default '0'               not null,
    block_kyc              tinyint unsigned       default '0'               not null comment 'Блокировка для не верифицированных пользователей',
    block_jackpots         tinyint unsigned       default '0'               not null comment 'Не участвует в джекпотах',
    is_blocked_tournaments tinyint unsigned       default '0'               not null,
    is_wagering            tinyint                default 0                 null,
    is_bonuses             tinyint unsigned       default '0'               null,
    is_jackpots            tinyint unsigned       default '0'               not null,
    freespins              tinyint unsigned       default '0'               not null comment 'Участвует в фриспинах',
    has_demo               tinyint(1)             default 0                 not null,
    multiplier             decimal(8, 2) unsigned default 0.00              not null,
    image                  varchar(128)                                     null,
    sorting                int unsigned           default '0'               not null,
    created_at             timestamp              default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    updated_at             timestamp                                        null,
    blocked                smallint unsigned      default '0'               null,
    constraint string_id
        unique (string_id, aggregator),
    constraint games_ibfk_1
        foreign key (provider_id) references games_providers (id)
)
    engine = InnoDB;

create index provider_id
    on games (provider_id);
```

Table users

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table users
(
    id                       bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name                     varchar(255) charset utf8                         null,
    surname                  varchar(255)                                      null,
    email                    varchar(255)                                      null,
    phone                    varchar(12)                                       null,
    password                 varchar(255)                                      not null,
    user_group               tinyint(1)                                        not null,
    status                   tinyint(1)              default 0                 not null,
    network                  varchar(32)                                       null,
    network_uid              varchar(32)                                       null,
    login                    varchar(255)                                      not null,
    ip_registration          varchar(39)                                       not null,
    ip_auth                  varchar(39)                                       null,
    country                  varchar(3) charset utf8                           null,
    country_already_changed  tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null comment 'Страну можно изменить только один раз',
    birthday_already_changed tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null comment 'Дату рождения можно установить один раз',
    city                     varchar(255)                                      null,
    postcode                 varchar(15)                                       null,
    date_birth               date                                              null,
    date_registration        timestamp               default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    date_auth                timestamp                                         null,
    date_last_activity       timestamp                                         null,
    comment                  varchar(265)                                      null,
    affiliate_id             varchar(32) charset utf8                          null,
    affiliate_user_id        varchar(255)                                      null,
    affiliate_company_id     varchar(32)                                       null,
    affiliate_payload        varchar(192) charset utf8                         null,
    affiliate_link_type      tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null comment 'Тип партнерской ссылки, по которой перешел юзер',
    favorite_bets            tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null comment 'Любимые ставки игрока',
    timezone                 varchar(64) charset utf8                          null,
    region                   varchar(255)                                      null,
    address                  varchar(265)                                      null,
    kyc_status               tinyint unsigned        default '1'               not null,
    role_id                  tinyint                                           null,
    sms_autentification      tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null,
    remember_token           varchar(100)                                      null,
    created_at               timestamp               default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    updated_at               timestamp                                         null,
    kyc_expire               date                                              null,
    sex                      varchar(1) charset utf8 default 'm'               null,
    login_attempt            int                     default 0                 not null,
    language                 varchar(2) charset utf8 default 'en'              not null,
    session_uuid             varchar(36)                                       null,
    session_token            varchar(64)                                       null,
    avatar                   varchar(265)                                      null,
    referral_user_id         bigint unsigned                                   null,
    level                    tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null,
    points                   int unsigned            default '0'               not null,
    shop_points              int unsigned            default '0'               not null,
    last_points_used         timestamp                                         null,
    max_withdrawal_amount    int unsigned                                      null,
    promocode_error_attempts int unsigned            default '0'               null,
    promocode_block_to       datetime                                          null,
    bonus_blocked            tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null comment 'Заблокирован для участия в бонусах',
    bonus_blocked_date       timestamp                                         null,
    blocked                  tinyint unsigned        default '0'               not null comment 'Блокировка Sumsub',
    service_status           varchar(32)                                       null comment 'Статус сервиса SumSub',
    constraint login
        unique (login),
    constraint network
        unique (network, network_uid),
    constraint users_email_unique
        unique (email),
    constraint users_ibfk_1
        foreign key (referral_user_id) references users (id)
            on update cascade
)
    engine = InnoDB
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index date_last_activity
    on users (date_last_activity);

create index referral_user_id
    on users (referral_user_id);
```

These two merged tables have combined 30 million rows, without GROUP BY statement, it executes within a 1.5-2 seconds. With GROUP BY, i can wait up to 5 minutes until it executes.

Obviously, i can execute script without GROUP BY, and then format and aggregate it in my code.
But so many records will breach the limit of my RAM, if i will save it in array or JSON.

Comment: You must optimize separate queries which are UNIONed in `popular_games` - nothing can be optimized after UNION.

Comment: @Akina yeah, i understand, but separate queries executes pretty quickly too, without the GROUP BY

Comment: If so then nothing can help. Server gathers separate queries outputs into inner buffer similar to temptable, then sorts and groups the rows. This combined outputs data is not sorted or indexed initially, so sorting and grouping needs in much time to be performed. You cannot optimize this... or at least I do not see the way to do this.

Comment: well if you are querying 30 million rows, why?  does it make sense to do based on some time period??? A given month?  2 months?  Otherwise, you may want to consider some pre-aggregate table even if by yearly bets that preserve totals, but why trying 30 million entries for totals repeatedly does not make much sense.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `count(user_id)` counts the number of *rows* that have `user_id IS NOT NULL`.  It seems like it won't be NULL, so you may as well do `COUNT(*)`.

In older versions `ANY_VALUE(date)` does not work but `MIN(date)` works.

There are lot of `IN(...)` lists; this makes it virtually impossible to fashion any useful `INDEXes`.  Here are some that could help:

```
transactions:  INDEX(status_id, type_id)
```

If it weren't for `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`, I would recommend doing the `SUMs` in each subquery, then adding the subtotals.

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?  How big are the tables (in GB)?  If things can't be cached adequately, then I/O is the problem and I will suggest changing `BIGINTs` (8 bytes each) to more civilized datatypes.

"two merged tables have combined 30 million rows" -- Is it 30M *before* or *after* filtering (`WHERE`)?

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`